# How to set date from one textbox with type="date" in other textboxes with type="date" using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

So i have a simple code

```
  EFFECTIVE DATE :  <asp:TextBox ID="txtEffectiveDate" type="date" CssClass="form-control form-control-sm" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

i want this date to be copied in other textboxes with type="date".

like in the textboxes below

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtIncentiveValue" type="number" Text="0" CssClass="form-control form-control-sm" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDateIncentive" type="date" CssClass="form-control form-control-sm" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: From where does `txtEffectiveDate` gets value from? Does user types into it or you are setting the value from code-behind?

Comment: It is a date picker with type="date",  the user picks a date and these dates need to reflect in other textboxes after being selected